# Refactoring two classes from third-party library that could have extended a base class

Tags: java, refactoring, third-party-libraries

I have two Classes, with very similar behaviors, both from a third party library.
Both needs to be populated with some value object and sent to specific queues in order for logging. Please note both of them does not have a common parent.

I am scratching my head to find out ways to refactor this.
Here is the sceanrio.

Class 1 : Apple
Class 2 : Orange

Unfortunately, Apple and Orange are not child classes of Fruit
And I can not change them to extend a base class.
Constructors of Apple and Orange have different signatures.

Current code:

```
if(isApple){
    Apple apple = new Apple(....);
    apple.setColor(Color.RED);
    apple.setPrice(10);
    apple.setCount(1000);

    AppleMQObject applMQObject = new AppleMQObject(apple);
    Producer appleProducer = Factory.create("apple-producer");
    appleProducer.send(applMQObject);
}else{
    Orange orange = new Orange(...);
    orange.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    orange.setPrice(30);
    orange.setCount(100);
    OrangeMQObject oMQObject = new oMQObject(orange);
    Producer orangeProducer = Factory.create("orange-producer");
    orangeProducer.send(orangeMQObject);
}
```

I can move the MQ code out to a common method. But how to handle the apple/orange situation.

Comment: What's your goal for the refactoring? I can see that you might want to avoid writing too many copies of the two blocks shown in your question, but unless there are lots more object types that you want to abstract away, it doesn't seem like a very pressing problem.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a single queue for all 'Fruit' objects?

Comment: This question is language specific - is this Java? C#? Anything else? In C++, you could solve this easily using templates; in C# this won't work with generics because the classes at stake would at least need a common interface.

Comment: .. in C#, one could create an (ugly) reflection hack, and I guess something similar is possible with Java, too.

Comment: What are the parameters passed to the `Apple` and `Orange` constructors?

Comment: `Apple` and `Orange` constructors have different signatures, language is Java, Goal of refactoring is to "not to repeat my self" - I m not trying to achieve single queue for Fruit objects.

Answer (score 3):

This is a refinement of @user2670177 answer:

If the function signatures of both are nearly the same it might be easier to use inheritance instead of composition.

Given you have Oranges and Appels you want to process

```
class Orange {
    public void setColor(Color color){}
    public void setPrice(int euroCents){}
    public void setCount(int numberOfItems){}
}

class Apple {
    public void setColor(Color color){}
    public void setPrice(int euroCents){}
    public void setCount(int numberOfItems){}
}
```

You can define a common interface for both

```
interface MyFruitInterface{
    void setColor(Color color);
    void setPrice(int euroCents);
    void setCount(int numberOfItems);
}
```

and attach the interface to the inherited class

```
class MyOrangeImpl extends Orange implements MyFruitInterface {
} 

class MyAppleImpl extends Apple implements MyFruitInterface {
}
```

Now your common code MQObject can handle both:

```
class MQObject {
    private MyFruitInterface fruit;
    MQObject(MyFruitInterface fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }

    void setPriceColorCount(int euroCents, Color color, int numberOfItems) {
        fruit.setPrice(euroCents);
        fruit.setColor(color);
        fruit.setCount(numberOfItems);
    }
}

void testMQ() {
    MQObject applMQObject = new MQObject(new MyAppleImpl());
    MQObject orangeMQObject = new MQObject(new MyOrangeImpl());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MyFruitInterface{
setColor();
setPrice;
..
}

MyOrangeImpl{
Orange o;

MyOrangeImpl(Orange o)
{
this.o = o;
}
setColor(Color C){
o.setColor(c);
}
setPrice(int price){
o.setPrice(price);
}
..
} 
MyAppleImpl{

Apple a;

MyAppleImpl(Apple a)
{
this.a = a;
}
setColor(Color C){
a.setColor(c);
}
setPrice(int price){
a.setPrice(price);
}
..
}
```

Now you have a common interface;

Comment: how does this answer the question asked?

Comment: +1 for using a common interface. For more Details see [Adapter_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Comment: -1 for code with no explanation of what it's doing.  @k3b's answer is a great example of how to explain code like this.